# Batch: sorting PDF's with letters and numbers in

Tags: sorting, batch-file

I am tasked with a batch sorting script. And i don't know how to start.

I have thousand of PDF files and they are generated with a number, some are generated with a letter either O or P, they need to be sorted into a separate folder.

For now all i got is:

```
xcopy "c:\Test 1" "c:\Test 1\sorted" /y
pause
```

But have no idea how to proceed.

//Merry Christmas

Comment: How exactly do you want them sorted?

Comment: "some are generated with a letter either O or P, they need to be sorted into a separate folder" - 1001 is good, 1001O needs to go to another folder. but the numbers vary. But mainly if it ends on O or P go to another folder.

Comment: So if it contains O it will go into another subfolder under Test 1\Sorted so Test 1\Sorted\O? Is a batch file a requirement? can you use powershell?

Comment: So if it contains O it will go into another subfolder under Test 1\Sorted. Yes, no and no.

Comment: So the ones that just have a number but no O or P get left, correct?

Comment: Correct. anything with P or O into sub folder. numbers stay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
@echo off
PUSHD "c:\Test 1"
MD SORTED 2>nul
FOR %%G IN (*O.pdf *P.PDF) DO MOVE "%%G" SORTED
POPD
```

Comment: This worked, Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF


set pathtoFolder="C:Test 1"
set destination="C:\Test 1\Sorted"

FOR /R %pathtoFolder% %%G IN (*O.txt *P.txt) DO (
  echo %%G
  xcopy %%G %destination% 
)
```

Based upon the comments, I'm assuming that the O and P are at the end of the file. Leave a comment if there are any errors, and I shall correct.

Comment: Why TWO FOR /R commands.  Just do it in one. `FOR /R %%G IN (*O.PDF *P.PDF)`

Comment: @Squashman - It's the only way I knew how do it. I'm reading Google, and other SO posts before I answer. Meh, your answer is better though

Comment: @Squashman - Check my updated answer

Comment: What would i need to change my self?

Comment: @TKChris - Check Updated answer, you don't need to change anything